# reference data member to instantiations of template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a base class which is a template, and two derived classes like below,

```
template <class parm>
class Base{
};

class Derived1: public Base<Derived1>
{};

class Derived2: public Base<Derived2>
{};
```

Now I have another class holding a reference to `Derived1` object or `Derived2` object depending on which is passed into the constructor, but I don't know the syntax, is it achievable in C++?

```
struct Observer{

  // I want to hold a reference to Derived1 or Derived2 based on 
  // which is passed into the constructor
  template <class parm>
  Base<parm> & derived_reference;

  Observer(Derived1 & d1):derived_reference(d1) // what's the right syntax here?
 {}

  Observer(Derived2 & d2):derived_reference(d2)
  {}
};
```

Comment: `Base<Derived1>` and `Base<Derived2>` are unrelated.

Comment: `variant<Derived1*, Derived2*>` (`std` in C++17, or `boost`) might help.

Comment: Else you may create a common base class to `Base<T>` (or just `Derived1`/`Derived2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // I want to hold a reference to Derived1 or Derived2 based on 
> // which is passed into the constructor
> template <class parm>
> Base<parm> & derived_reference;
> ```

Given your class structure, that is not possible.

There is no common base class of `Base<Derived1>` and `Base<Derived2>`.

---

You can introduce another class as a base of `Base<T>` to pull off something that will be usable.

```
struct RealBase { virtual ~RealBase() {} };

template <class parm>
class Base : public RealBase {};

class Derived1: public Base<Derived1>
{};

class Derived2: public Base<Derived2>
{};

struct Observer{

   RealBase& derived_reference;

   Observer(Derived1& d1):derived_reference(d1)
   {}

   Observer(Derived2& d2):derived_reference(d2)
   {}
};
```

That will be useful if you have `virtual` member functions in `RealBase`. Otherwise, you'll have to use `dynamic_cast` in client code for it to be useful.

Comment: `RealBase` is mostly as useful than `void*` if it is not polymorphic (for at least `dynamic_cast`).